# How to install GRPC in Xampp Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: php, xampp

I have installed xampp on my ubnutu machine. I try to install grpc. so the pecl is preinstalled in xampp which is found in `/opt/lampp/bin`.

I try to install like this `sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install grpc`. but i get this error
`ERROR: /tmp/pear/temp/grpc/configure --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config' failed` [Please check the error screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rTeX.png)

Comment: If you are using 20.10 it went EOL in April 2021 and is off topic on this site. you can post your question on this other site https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error does not seem to have anything to do with XAMPP, per se, but the absence of a C compiler. You will want to install it first:

1. Ensure `apt` is up to date:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Install the `build-essential` package, which contains everything you will need to compile C code:

   ```
   sudo apt install build-essential
   ```
3. Try your installation again